# Percentage Calculation in PHP in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am looking to make a percentage calculation on an FPDF based invoice template which contains `$total` (e.g 1000) and a number value `$percentage` (e.g. 20)

Ideally I would like this to display as discount

```
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, 'Discount' .$discountresult. '', 0, 'L');
```

How to achieve this? Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the $discountresult come from? Also you are missing some "" marks in your syntax.

Comment: Are you asking how to do basic math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$total = 1000;
$percentage = 20;

$discountResult =  $total - (($percentage / 100) * $total);

$pdf->Cell(100, 5, 'Discount' . $discountResult, 0, 'L');
```